# Видимость элемента на странице в asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Создал master page. И далее создаю от master page страницу и на эту страницу добавляю элемент label.

Но когда захожу в в код данной страницы, чтобы в обработчик load страницы написать мой label, Visual Studio начинает ругаться, что такого элемента не существует. Не могу понять почему не видит его?

Вот сама страница с элементом lblAbout:

```
<%@ Page Title="О нас" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="lblAbout" runat="server" Text="Об авторе"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

В codebehind не видит lblAbout.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо убедиться, что VS добавила код в *.designer.cs файл.
В вашем случае необходимо в Solution Explorer найти файл About.aspx.designer.cs и убедиться, что элемент label там существует.

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblAbout;
```

Answer (score 0):

В студии можно редактировать страницы только те, на которых ты находишься в данный момент. Т.е. если лейбл находится на мастере, то ты его не можешь править с дочерней страницы.